# Fetch Html code of Sendgrid Dynamic Template

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Is their anyway to save the html template of sendgrid through template id as Template_id remains the same But the previous template keep changing. So that user can actually preview what was the actual email being send to him

Expecting to save the HTML Code of specific dynamic template of sendgrid with id and API key